# Product custom option price scope issue in admin side

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

1. Create a Magento environment with multiple websites and store views
2. Create a simple product
3. Add a custom option to the product with different values with different pricing
4. Save the product
5. Change the store view scope you are editing in and change the pricing of the custom options
6. Save
7. Review the custom option pricing at default and other storeview scopes

But Price of the custom option is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find solution to this question Magento 1.x & Magento 2.x

**Magento 1.x**

Find code `$baseCurrency = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();` in file `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Option\Value.php`

and replace to code `$baseCurrency = Mage::app()->getStore($object->getStoreId())->getBaseCurrencyCode();`

**Magento 2.x**

Find bellow code in file `\magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\Value.php`

```
$baseCurrency = $this->_config->getValue(
                \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                'default'
            );
```

and replace to bellow code

```
$baseCurrency = $this->_storeManager->getStore($object->getStoreId())->getBaseCurrencyCode();
```

**Note:**  First move file in local and put above code in that file